# Image background which stick to top React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, background, native-base

I want to achieve the following view, where i have a blue image which is added as a background sticking to the top of the container. Any idea on how this can be achieved in React Native?
P.S. I am using Native Base too in the project

[image]

Comment: By default `flexDirection` is `column` so by simply adding image to the container, it sticks to the top of the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
    const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
          }}>
          <Image
            resizeMode={'contain'}
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_51113407033_7bed78119e_z_640_360_nofilter.jpg',
            }}
            style={{ width: windowWidth, height: 300, position: 'absolute' }}
          />
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', paddingBottom: 10 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: windowWidth * 0.8,
                height: 350,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                alignSelf: 'center',
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: copy paste here [link](https://snack.expo.dev/) If you want to test out online

Comment: Thanks alot Bhrugu for your answer , however fixing the height of the image is creating issues. As, the image is being cropped vertically in some screens

Comment: I have put my image https://snack.expo.dev/-9e6FS7cq .Do check the android variant

Comment: @AshishKumar add this props in image  `resizeMode={'contain'}` you can put it in style also.

Comment: I will update my answer as well.